# Passing variable with button (Ajax Modal)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, button

In table (that contains records, customers credentials, from my db) I have a *delete* button for each row.
I want that if I click on the delete button, this will delete the row, passing the ID of the record to the **deletecustomer.php**
When I click on the delete button, I have a ajax modal that ask if you want to confirm the action or not.
The problem is that if I click on CONFIRM (in the modal), my modal will go in delete-utente.php (where I have the query for the delete of the row) but the ID isn't passed. 
In delete-utente.php I have a message if the query it's ok (delete complete), and another message if the delete can't be done. 
After I click confirm I always have the OK message, but the customer has not been deleted.
I guess that the problem is not the **deletecustomer.php** because if I use a simple javascript alert, the query it's ok and I pass the identifier successful, but with the ajax modal, the identifier is not passed.

It's the first time that I use ajax, so I think that the problem it's ajax code.

code of the table in my main page (newcustomer.php)

```
<table class="simple-table responsive-table" method="POST" id="customer-list">
//code thead
//rows rows..
<?php echo '<button type="input" class="button icon-trash with-tooltip confirm" onclick="openConfirm()" href="deletecustomer.php?customerid='.$idcustomer.'" title="Delete"></button>'; ?>
//....
</table>
```

ajax modal

```
function openConfirm()
        {
            $.modal.confirm('Sicuri di voler cancellare il cliente?', function()
            {
                window.location.href = "deletecustomer.php"; //the php file where I have the delete query


            }, function()
            {
                window.location.href = "newcustomer.php";

            });
        };
```

and I take the values in my deletecustomer.php like this

```
$customeridd=(int) $_GET['customerid'];
```

Sorry if is a stupid mistake or a stupid question ^^"
And thank in advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this :

```
<?php 
  echo '<button type="input" class="button icon-trash with-tooltip confirm" onclick="openConfirm('.$idcustomer.')" href="deletecustomer.php?customerid='.$idcustomer.'" title="Delete">button</button>'; 
?>
```

And

```
function openConfirm(id)
    {
        alert(id);
        $.modal.confirm('Sicuri di voler cancellare il cliente?', function()
        {
            window.location.href = "deletecustomer.php?customerid="+id; //the php file where I have the delete query


        }, function()
        {
            window.location.href = "newcustomer.php";

        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
<?php echo '<a class="button icon-trash with-tooltip confirm" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure?\');" href="deletecustomer.php?customerid='.$idcustomer.'">Delete</a>'; ?>
```